# Real-time countdown timer with concurrent user input in Python

Tags: python, date, input, time, real-time

I'm developing a Python program where I need to implement a countdown timer that visibly decreases by one second at a time, while also allowing the user to input their answers. The timer should update in real-time, displaying only the changing time portion (seconds), without the use of clearing the screen or multiple print statements. The goal is to create a seamless user experience without unnecessary distractions.

Here's a simplified version of the code I have so far:

```
import time
import threading

def countdown(seconds):
    for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):
        print(f"Time Remaining: {i} seconds")
        time.sleep(1)

def get_user_input():
    user_input = input("Enter your answer: ")
    print(f"Your answer: {user_input}")

def main():
    countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(10,))
    countdown_thread.start()

    get_user_input()

    countdown_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With the current implementation, the timer functions correctly, but it halts the program during the countdown, preventing the user from entering their answer until the countdown finishes. Additionally, using print statements in a loop creates multiple lines, cluttering the output.

Is there a way to modify this code to achieve a real-time countdown timer that updates without clearing the screen or relying on multiple print statements? I want to create a clean and seamless user experience where the changing time portion is displayed on a single line while allowing concurrent user input.

Any suggestions, alternative approaches, or code examples that address these requirements would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what you're asking for is in the realm of using things like https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html to create rich TUIs